# Echo different and one row in each image taking the last 2 rows in the database

Tags: php, database, echo, rows

My code display all values in the database in an single image, i want each image to display only one value in the database starting from the last 2 values.Any help? below is my code

```
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <img src="grey.jpg">            

       <div class="top-left"> <p><?php $servername = "localhost";
           $username = "root";
           $password = "";
           $dbname = "software";

            // Create connection
           $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
           // Check connection
           if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT ID, description FROM test";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

             //if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
           // output data of each row

           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo " ". $row["description"]. "<br>";
           }

         //} else {
          // echo "0 results";
         //} ?> </p></div>

   </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
     <img src="imagesb.jpg">
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is super unclear and confusing. Please edit your question with a _proper_ description of what you want and what currently happens.

Comment: The code i inserted display all values in the database in an single images. But i want each single value to display in each image starting from the last 2 values in the database. Any help??

Comment: That's not even close to a proper explanation. That's basically just repeating the text in the question.

Comment: What do you mean, values displaying “in” an image? I don’t see you doing any dynamic image manipulation or creation here, the images appear to be static.

Comment: I have a slideshow which shows up 2 images at a time. My code display all values in a table in the database in the first image. But I want each image to display one single value in the table in the database starting with the last 2 values in the tables.

Comment: I mean text displaying in an image. That text come from a table in the database. It displays all values as text in the image. I want to display one single value in each image.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last two rows from the DB using something like

```
SELECT ID, description FROM test ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2
```

(or whichever column you want to order by).

As for how you want it output it's not clear what you're asking but it sounds like you want to move the while loop outside of the div tag. Something like...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "software";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, description FROM test ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2"; // Last 2 rows
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="grey.jpg">
        <div class="top-left">
            <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["description"], ENT_QUOTES); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <img src="imagesb.jpg">
    </div>
<?php endwhile;
```

Remember whenever you output any variables/DB content you need to escape it (htmlspecialchars in this case) otherwise your page could be hacked. Here is a random link I found about it that covers the basics https://www.inanimatt.com/php-output-escaping.html

Comment: Yeah but i want to display only one value in one and each image in the slider.